# Scraping after login with Mechanize python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to scrape a website to access my school grades faster. So far I have this.

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import html2text

br = mechanize.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

# Browser options
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_gzip(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)


br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Chrome')]

# The site we will navigate into, handling it's session
br.open('https://pamet-sapphire.k12system.com/CommunityWebPortal/Welcome.cfm')

for f in br.forms():
    print f

br.form = list(br.forms())[0]

# User credentials
br.form['j_username'] = ''
br.form['j_password'] = ''
br.form['j_pin'] = ''

# Login
br.submit()


print br.response()

resp = br.open('https://pamet-sapphire.k12system.com/CommunityWebPortal/Welcome.cfm').read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(resp)

#for link in soup.findAll('a'):
#    print link
#    print '\n'
```

When I try reading the response, the browser is still on the login page and I get the HTML of the login page. I know I am opening the same website again, but when you log in to this website, it stays on the same page but the information on it changes. Is there any reason what I am doing now does not work?

Comment: Since this is javascript you may not be able to use Mechanize.  I would just send your login info to the server using `urllib2` and see what you get using that method.

Comment: @Jkdc Alright, thanks. I'll try urllib2. Just curious, what types of things can mechanize work with, just plain html?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah.  Also, there is a field (in addition to `j_username`, `j_password`, `j_pin`) called `javascript` and it's sent with the POST as `true`.  I haven't messed much with Mechanize so I don't know if you need to be including that somehow in the form or not.  Everything I deal with is Java so I've strayed away from Mechanize, maybe someone else can elaborate.